# one server bind different ports

Tags: c, sockets

I am a newbie in C. Now I let my server create two threads listening to two different ports, both of them will call `bind a port->listen()->accept()`. Then there are two clients connecting to these two ports respectively. Then these two threads will `accept()` and generate two file descriptors. What I am curious is that is it possible that the generated file descriptors can be the same integers?

Comment: Descriptors are *per process*, not per thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file descriptor is something that you are not expected to interpret - So it is actually "not your business" to know this ;)

*Within a process*, file descriptors returned from system calls are guaranteed to be *unique*. So the two threads will receive two different integers (actually, multi-threading does not affect this question at all. The result is the same as if both sockets would have been opened in the main thread).

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that descriptors will get recycled within the life time of one process.

Answer (score 1):

They might be the same integers, if the first thread will close the new socket before the accept on a second socket will create a new socket - file descriptors are recycled.

Comment: In my opinion,  there is no such thing as a 'closed file descriptor' - once the file is closed, the descriptor becomes just an arbitrary integer.

Comment: @tofro, I am inclined to agree, though I am not sure what is the practical significance of this.